# Should complexity formatted as code be updated to use MathJax?

Tags: discussion, editing, markdown

I saw [a post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/176181/120114) that mentions algorithmic complexity and formats such complexity values using inline code spans (e.g. `O(n)`). Should that post be updated to use MathJax formatting, [since that is an option](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1708/120114) instead of inline code spans?

Comment: Heavy mathjax usually slows done page rendering. On stackoverflow it is a real problem for me, as it is more "fast paced". The only problem I see with it on CR is that not everyone is familiar with it. I still cannot write anything complicated without a cheatsheet.

Comment: The only other argument I could think of is what happened on ppcg: the mathjax got removed after a point. But here on codereview, it doesn't seem like that will be a problem, seeing as the mathjax was added quite some time ago.

Comment: A downside to MathJax is that it involves 3rd-party Javascript; it's not obvious that enabling another site will make the post more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not? Especially if there's more to edit than just a single instance of `O(n)`... I presume screen readers treat MathJax differently than inline code, too.

I wouldn't make an edit *just for that* (especially with <2K rep and the edit needing to be reviewed/approved), but as part of an otherwise legitimate worthwhile edit that's improving the post, I don't see a problem with that.

I'd probably leave alone an otherwise clearly worded, correctly formatted post without any typos and just that single `O(n)` though.

Comment: Okay thanks! [post edited](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/176181/120114)

Answer (score -2):

I have mixed feelings about mathjax for BigO notation **in lieu of BigO notation as `code`**. Mathjax makes writing and editing BigO notation harder without significantly improvements to clarity.

MathJax is esoteric not ubiquitous. It is not an extension of Markdown, but a syntax unto itself...ok its like LaTex...but LaTeX is the *lingua franca* of papers for academic journals, not the web.

In short, I don't see what problem editing BigO notation from `code` to MathJax solves. I see several potential usability problems it creates for people without LaTeX experience: i.e. the vast majority of people.